# Laravel error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project in order to get a better handle of Laravel 5.2 . The project is a simple app which takes a quote from the SQL database and displays it to the user. The user has an input field where he inputs his answer. If the user's input matches the author name, he gets a notification and his score increments by one, and the the next question is displayed. If the answer is incorrect, he is shown the correct answer and the next question is displayed.

The error is referring to this line of code in my blade template page:

```
@if(Session::has('index'))
           {{ $i = Session::get('index')}}

            <h3 class="text-center">" {{$quotes[$i]->quote}} " </h3>

                {{$currentId = $quotes[$i]->author_id}}


            @endif
```

If I was to render `$i` by itself, like so: `{{$i}}`, I get the correct numerical value.

Here is the code in the controller responsible for setting the session variable:

```
if (!$request->session()->has('index')) {
            $index = 1;     
            $request->session()->set('index', $index);      
        } else {
            $index = $index + 1;
            $request->session()->set('index', $index);
        }
```

**Edit1**: The $quotes array works fine, if I was choose a number, as in 
$quotes[0]->quote, I get the correct string.

**Edit2**: Provided background information on the problem. See above.

Comment: where are you setting `$quotes`

Comment: Hi, please have a look at the edit (:

Comment: What if you use the exact number that you're passing in as index? Ultimately if you pass in a number that doesn't exist within quotes, you're going to get that error.

Comment: Fair question, but I set the value of index to 1 in my controller, and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this.  This does not have the logic in the view itself but rather in the controller where I believe it belongs anyway.

**Controller:**

```
public function show() 
{
    if (!$request->session()->has('index')) {
        $index = 1;     
        $request->session()->set('index', $index);      
    } else {
        $index = $index + 1;
        $request->session()->set('index', $index);
    }
    $quote = Quote::getById($index); //make this method

    return view('quote', compact('quote'));
}
```

Then in your view:

```
        <h3 class="text-center">" {{$quote->quote}} " </h3>

        {{$currentId = $quote->author_id}}
```

Your Model for Quote would do something like:

```
public function getById($id)
{
    return Quote::find($id);
}
```

It is best in my opinion to keep any business logic out of your views and place it in your controller or model itself.  You can also create a set of `quote` classes that deals with how you handle quotes.

Comment: I completely agree with you on separating the business logic from the view, but your solution doesn't solve my problem, which I am afraid is because I didn't explain it properly. Please have a look at my updated post if you can. Thank you for taking the time to right out such a detailed response (: